# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'expenseswebsite.userpreferences'

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

Good day dear Community!
Got a following error at the PyCharm Terminal:

`File "C:\NewDjangoProjects\django-income-expense-website\expenseswebsite\expenses\views.py", line 9, in <module>from expenseswebsite.userpreferences.models import UserPreference ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'expenseswebsite.userpreferences'`

here below my expenses\views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Category, Expense
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
from expenseswebsite.userpreferences.models import UserPreference
```

here below my UserPreference\models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserPreference(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(user)+'s preferences'
```

Hierarchy:

```
django-income-expense-website
\
 \__expenseswebsite
        \   \  \  \  \_authentication(migr, models, views etc..)
         \   \  \  \__expenses       (migr, models, views etc..)
          \   \  \____expenseswebsite(migr, models, views etc..)
           \   \______templates
            \_________userpreferences(migr, models, views etc..)
```

All migrations are migrated/applied successfully and
there is no any red underlined text inside PyCharm Editor window, so what is wrong with
that import?

Thanks for any help in adavnce!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python root of you app is the `expenseswebsite`, so you should import this with:

```
from userpreferences.models import UserPreference
```

Furthermore in order to load the app correctly, `'userpreferences'` should be in the `INSTALLED_APPS` *before* the `'expenses'` app, so:

```
# settings.py

# ⋮

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ⋮,
    'userpreferences',
    # ⋮,
    'expenses',
    # ⋮
]

# ⋮
```

You likely should mark the `expensewebsite` as root in your PyCharm project such that the IDE can help with import statements in the future. For more information, see the [*Assign a category to a folder in the Project tool window* section of the PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html#mark-dir-project-view).

Comment: Hi, Willem! Yes, I tried to make it so but in that case ```from userpreferences.models import UserPreference``` UserPreference underlined in red

Comment: @Ches_Ter: that is, like I said, because you need to mark the `expensewebsite` as the *source root*. Otherwise PyCharm thinks that the directory above it is the source root, and this it assumes the import statement should be different.

Comment: @Ches_Ter: please look at the link at the bottom how to set the source root.

Comment: Thanks! I did it. Already set it (settings->project str-> add content root) and change installed apps order and change import UserPreference as You advised now the issue is ```File "C:\NewDjangoProjects\django-income-expense-website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
userpreferences.models.UserPreference.DoesNotExist: UserPreference matching query does not exist.``` It seems now I get the problem with my venv which is in the  django-income-expense-website located

Comment: @Ches_Ter: well that means it now queries for a `UserPreference` object, but can not find one, but it thus referred to the right model.

Comment: @Ches_Ter: I advise to ask a new question with the error regarding that it can not find the `UserPreference` *database* record. This should contain the view that is triggering the error. The location of the `venv` is not important, since the working directory is where the `manage.py` is located.

Comment: yeah! I think so, thanks a lot for Your soonest reply)) I'll keep digging follow..